# How to deploy my Android project and how to test on my device

Tags: android, deployment

I'm a beginner for Android Development. So, i have need to deploy my Android project and how to install into my Android device. (like, mobile, tab.. ) I have a Android mobile xperia x10.

Please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First option is to use your IDE. Eclipse(with ADT) and IntelliJ Idea supports deployment on device. THe only thing you should have installed is mobile phone driver. HTC, for example, has it on it's sdcard.

Second option is just copying an apk file to your sdcard and installing it by invoking apk from some file manager like ASTRO.